# Where can I get the Cadinput plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, line, cad

From Stackexchange, I got to know that Cadinput plugin could do this work. I need to create a line feature specifying the desired length and bearing in an open source GIS (Preferably QGIS) as in CAD drawing. This is for the creation of floor plan of a building.

Answer (score 1):

I think the repository you are looking for is https://github.com/olivierdalang/CadInput. Plugins-Manage and install plugins and you can give the repository there in order to install and use this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will let you know what turns out